# remapping multiple files in condor using transfer_output_remaps

Tags: condor

I'm using condor to run parallel jobs of a python script that returns two different files: F1 and F2. If I apply transfer_output_remaps to both of them so as to rename the file (by associating it with the process number) and mapping it to a different directory, i.e.

```
transfer_output_remaps="F1=/home/OutDir/F1$(Process)"
transfer_output_remaps="F2=/home/OutDir/F2$(Process)"
```

Following the execution, OutDir/ only contains the F2 file. This is not due to any error in the script I'm running, i.e. if I only have the first transfer_output_command, F1 maps correctly.

What is the correct way to use transfer_output_remaps to perform the rename/file transfer on both output files?

Answer (score 0):

Subsequent lines in the `condor_submit` file overwrite previous lines.  `transfer_output_remaps` takes a semicolon separate list of remaps, so try a line like

```
transfer_output_remaps = "F1=/home/OutDir/F1$(Process);F2=/home/OutDir/F2$(Process)"
```